# An immortal crazy hen

Tags: probability-theory

An immortal hen was put in an empty house.
Every day she lays $2$ eggs, and every evening she breaks $1$ unbroken egg, chosen uniformly at random from the remaining unbroken eggs.

What is the probability that in "the end of the process" there will be unbroken eggs?

My teacher said it's zero, but I didn't really understand.

Can someone explain why it is, or not?

Comment: Nothing in this problem appears to be probabilistic except the parenthetical ("in uniform distribution"), which makes no sense.

Comment: Just checking: she lays two eggs on day 1, then breaks 1. So there's 1 left. The next day, she lays two  more eggs, for a total of 3 eggs, and breaks 1, leaving 2 eggs. At night on day $n$, there are $n$ eggs. Are you sure you've written up the question correctly? In this way, there's always unbroken eggs.

Comment: Just prior to zero eggs, however, there would be enough eggs to create a black hole.

Comment: Is the house assumed to be immortal too?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox

Comment: @AlexR. you got it right

Comment: @mjqxxxx the teacher used Borrel-canteli and a sequence of random-vars

Comment: Are you *sure* the hen doesn't try to break *each* egg with some probability $p$? Why would you need Borel Cantelli for the current question?????

Comment: @AlexR: She is choosing the egg to break at random.  So it's possible (though almost surely false) that a *particular* egg lives forever.  The question is whether it's also a.s. true that *no* egg lives forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slightly less extreme version of the [Ross-Littlewood paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox): every step you add two eggs, and every step you remove one egg.  The real question is: for any given egg, is it still there at the end of time?

Let's consider an egg that is laid on day $n$.  on this day, there are $n+1$ eggs from which to choose, so the probability it survives its first day is $n/\left(n+1\right)$; the probability it survives its second day (having survived the first) is $(n+1)/(n+2)$, etc.  This gives a total probability that it survives to the end of time of
$$\prod_{k=n}^\infty \frac{k}{k+1}$$
Which is a telescoping product: for any finite $n$, this limits to $n/\infty = 0$.  So any given egg has probability $0$ of surviving to the end of time.  Whether this means that no eggs remain is another matter!

Comment: Impressive mind-reading. +1.

Comment: well,that's all I could figure out also,but I just could not see how to answer the question with this(pherhaps it is'nt a good question,as I see by the votes).thanks for the link!